# Android Query: Trying to retrieve Bitmap Image from URL?

Tags: java, android, url, bitmap, android-query

I'm trying to retrieve a Bitmap image from a URL using [Android Query](https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery). However I'm left with no Bitmap whatsoever. This is my code:

```
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    private int w = 700, h = 480;
    private Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
    private AQuery aq;
    final ArrayList<Bitmap> bbf = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    aq = new AQuery(LookBookFlipActivity.this);

    aq.ajax("http://www.newyorker.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Stokes-Hello-Kitty2-1200.jpg",Bitmap.class,0,new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
    @Override
    public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
        if(object != null)
        {
            bmp = object;
            bbf.add(bmp);
        }
    }
 });
```

And when I print out the ArrayList bbf's size, it returns zero which means either the bitmap isnt properly saved in the bmp variable or its not getting added to the arraylist. Help me out please :)

Comment: Is your image url proper??

Comment: Haha I just added a demo URL for StackOverflow but yes the real URL I use works well :) @PiyushGupta

Comment: I know its a demo url but if ur image url is not proper them bitmap will not generate

Comment: Okay updated @PiyushGupta

Comment: I just want the URL to be added to that Bitmap ArrayList :)@PiyushGupta

Comment: Can u put a log inside if(object != null)
        {
            bmp = object;
            bbf.add(bmp);
        } and check if object is null or not?

Comment: @AtulOHolic it goes in to the condition which means its not null

Comment: In that case, try adding object directly to the ArrayList as bbf.add(object) and then try to check the size of it.